# The name contains invalid characters

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm having a problem with the following script.  When listing parameters that are optional I've used the "" before, so I can't figure out why this isn't working.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

path = "C:/Data_new/Temp/Default.gdb"
name = "point_shapefile.shp"
type = "POINT"

m = "DISABLED"
z = "DISABLED"
prjFile = "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Desktop10.0/Coordinate Systems/Projected Coordinate Systems" + \
      "/State Plane/NAD 1983 (US Feet)/NAD 1983 StatePlane North Carolina FIPS 3200 (US Feet).prj"
reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(prjFile)

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, name, type, "", m, z, reference)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? "Name contains invalid characters"?

Answer (score 5):

Lose the `.shp` in `name`, since your workspace is a geodatabase -- no file extension required.

Alternatively, change `path` to a regular folder instead of a geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks...dropping the .shp did the trick.  I could have sworn that I've used it before in other scripts, but now I know.

Comment: Another little tip especially on Windows is to prepend an 'r' to the front of path strings.  This tells Python to treat it as a raw string and it automatically escapes the slashes.  This way you avoid accidentally passing things like newline (/n) and many other special characters.  So your 4th line would read: path = r"C:/Data_new/Temp/Default.gdb".  Obviously, this wasn't your problem here but it's a common 'gotcha' and so a good habit to add that little 'r' (and a heck of a lot quicker/thorough than manually escaping the slashes!).

Answer (score 2):

While your issue really turned out to be a code writing issue, I'll answer the question that was asked.

Rather than simply using double quotes for your optional parameters, you should really consider using a quoted pound sign ("#"), as noted in the help article [Executing tools in the Python window](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002100000019000000) under the "Required versus optional parameters" subsection.

> Optional parameters have default values. If you enter a quoted #
>   (pound sign), "" (two double quotes), '' (two single quotes), or a
>   Python None for an optional parameter, the default parameter value
>   will be used. For keywords, the default value is the first keyword in
>   the list. See the help for an individual tool for its default
>   parameter values.

Using a quoted pound sign will make it much more obvious to future code readers (and likely writer) that it is an intentionally set default parameter, rather than a potentially forgot about parameter that never got filled in.

Comment: What makes code even more clear is to specify parameters by name, e.g. `spatial_reference=reference` instead of just `reference` -- the added bonus being that parameters can be listed in any order and optional parameters using default values can be omitted completely.